# C++ : Slicing to base rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I came across the following code and I couldn't find on google why the following statement is valid C++ :

```
Base&& b = Derived();
```

Please explain or give reference

Here is a sample code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base{
public:
    virtual ~Base(){}
    virtual void say_hi() { cout << "hi base"; }
};
class Derived : public Base{
public:
    virtual ~Derived(){}
    virtual void say_hi() { cout << "hi derived"; }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Base&& b = Derived();
    b.say_hi();

    return 0;
}
```

prints :

```
hi derived
```

Comment: Would you understand why `Derived d; Base& b = d;` would be valid? If so, can you [edit] your question to explain where you feel the difference is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is binding a temporary to an r-value reference. Temporaries may be bound to both constant l-value references and r-value references.

As for why it's properly calling the derived function, that's because you're calling a virtual function. Dynamic dispatch is taking place as normal.

This is sort of the same as using a function call with an r-value reference parameter:

```
void callHi(Base&& b){
  b.say_hi();
}

...

callHi(Derived{}); // ultimately calls derived say_hi method
```

You mention slicing. For slicing to occur, [the sequence of events is a bit more complex than simply calling a virtual function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14461532/4892076)

Comment: References are references, plain and simple. +1